# Transferring money to Indian private bank

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer, balance-transfer

I work for a friend overseas who want to pay me through SKRILL (MONEYBOOKERS - PAYPAL like service) in USD. I would have my Moneybookers account linked to my Savings Bank Account in a private indian bank. If I transfer US $5000 per month, will my bank investigate about the source of income in details? If yes, what proof I need to provide ?

Comment: Have you tried asking your private Indian bank? Bank-to-bank transfers of funds via SWIFT transfers through Indian _public_ banks require the _remitter_ to provide the reason for the transfer; MONEYBOOKERS might not, and your _private_ bank may well have internal rules that are different from the rules that public (regulated) banks have to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Any such amount has to be reported by Skrill and the Bank to RBI. As long as your earnings are legitimate and you are paying the taxes you shouldn't be worried. If its for services rendered, you would have a contract and / or invoice ... ie some paper work. It is important to keep the paper work in order.